# What's the book people are saying converts old Monk archetypes to the Unchained monk?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk, product-identification, conversion, unchained

I've been researching about the Unchained Monk lately and I've seen people mention a third party product that attempts to update all old Monk archetypes to function and be balanced for the Unchained monk. Does anyone know which book it is and where I could purchase it?

Comment: …and as mentioned in answer to this [question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87272/8610).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further googling allowed me to find these 2 books, though they are not Paizo-official sources:

- [Everyman Unchained: Monk Archetypes](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/148239/Everyman-Unchained-Monk-Archetypes)
- [Unchained Monk Archetypes (PFRPG)](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/149999/Unchained-Monk-Archetypes-PFRPG)

Unless anyone else can tell which of those 2 is the best or knows a better one, I will be marking this as answered.