# Multiple Styles During a Full Round Attack

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, monk, fighting-style, unchained

I have a 16th Level Unchained Monk designed and ready to play. However, I'm getting a little caught up with the Style Feats. I have three different styles (Mantis, Wolf, and Pummeling) along with Combat Style Mastery.

With a build of this sort, can I start in Mantis Style to attempt a Stunning Fist Attack, than as a free action switch to Wolf style attempt a Trip, then as another free action switch to Pummeling Style and finish off the rest of my attacks?

Comment: @HeyICanChan The Character has no Archetype. Is a generic Lvl 16 Unchained Monk. As far as i can tell there should be no limit to it, unfortunetly i am unsure about the ruling about taking so many Free Actions a turn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is exactly what the text on [Combat Style Master](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/combat-style-master-combat/) says:

> You can switch your style as a free action. At the start of combat, pick one of your styles. You start the combat in that style, even in the surprise round.

On the definition of a [free action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Free-Action):

> Free actions consume a very small amount of time and effort. You can perform one or more free actions **while taking another action** normally.

Note that the number of free actions available is limited by your GM.

> However, there are reasonable limits on what you can really do for free, as decided by the GM.

Comment: The last portion is imporatant because switching between styles is the exact kind of Free Action a GM might restrict. Personally, I'd probably only allow two styles to be used in one Full Attack/Flurry. I could absolutely see all three being allowed by other GM's, though.

Comment: It boils down to preference, but swapping weapon hands is a free action, grabbing an arrow is a free action, quick-drawing throwing daggers are free actions. And when a character has 4+ iterative attacks, we allow all of those more than twice per round.

Comment: Like I said, I could definitely see it being aloud. I, as a GM, consider altering *how* you are making attacks (to the extent of changing styles) to be more difficult that simply doing the same repetitive task. That being said, there are feats that make loading crossbows a Free action that can be done multiple times per round so it's definitely a reasonable use of the Feat. Of course if I was a GM I'd probably ask why not just Master of Many Styles. Not my player, not my place to question though.

Comment: I think UMonk doesn't qualify for MoMS.

Comment: @ShadowKras Yes to my understanding Unchained Monks do not qualify for any of the original Monk Archetype.

Comment: @RichardFitzinwell [You'd be right](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87272/8610) (unless something's changed since Aug.)

Comment: Yeah there's maybe 3 or 4 archetypes that work. I overlooked the Unch part tbh